# How can I make PhotoSwipe work in different directions?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I mean, normal actions of `PhotoSwipe` is to scroll horizontally and to close after vertical swipe. I would like to switch actions so it scrolls vertically and closes after horizontal swipe.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely need to download the source from [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/) and make the changes yourself.

Looking at the `_panOrMoveMainScroll` method in `src/js/gestures.js`, it appears that the panning logic is only present for horizontal gestures `_direction === 'h' && axis === 'x'`, whereas the mainScroll is present for vertical gestures.

If you think this is useful enough to warrant the development effort, I'd recommend taking the latest branch and adding a default option in `core.js` that allows the directions to be toggled and issuing a pull request to the original repository. This way future users can benefit from your effort and simply set a property to switch the directions.

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it =)